# Get only depth data from Kinect using libfreenect

Tags: ros, kinect, ros-kinetic, libfreenect, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In order to reduce the amount of CPU freenect nodelet is using on my robot I would like to get only the topic "camera/depth_registered/image_raw" cause this is the only one I need right now.

In case this is not posible, I would like to know if I can run freenect nodelet remotely. I try but as the camera is not connected to the PC running it I get the message "No devices connected". Is there any way by which I could execute it remotely?

And another problem I have is that if I execute "depthimage_to_laserscan" module in the remote PC (after launching freenect in the robot connected to Kinect) it does not work (I do not get any errors or warnings but the /scan topic does not show anything), however, in the robot it does work. Could it be cause one of ROS versions is Kinetic and the other one Indigo? This is the launch file:

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300718/get-only-depth-data-from-kinect-using-libfreenect/) by [kuka_kuka](https://answers.ros.org/users/36195/kuka_kuka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The depth data from the Kinect is acquired processing the infrared (IR) map and the camera map. I believe there isn't a way to acquire the depth data without the other nodes.

I believe you can't access the data remotely because you're trying directly from a PC to access the Kinect in other pc. You should use the same PC connected to the Kinect to acquire the data and in other pc just subscribe to camera/depth_registered/image_raw in the other pc.

---

Originally posted by [FelipeNascimento](https://answers.ros.org/users/37001/felipenascimento/) with karma: 51 on 2018-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0